# How to replace headers with comments in a query result?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to query a table which table's field names are unable to identify, eg: `akb12`, `ake32`...

But the field comments are significative, so I want to replace headers with comments in the query result. And the table is too big to use "AS" to replace.

normal result:

```
akb12  |  ake32
value1 |  value2
```

what I want:

```
akb12's comment | ake32's comment
value1          |   value2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If comments are already stored in your database you can query `user_col_comments`. Here is an example for table `test` with some columns commented:

```
create table test (a, b, c) as (
  select 1, 'B1', 'C101' from dual union all
  select 2, 'B2', 'C102' from dual );

comment on column test.a is 'Id';
comment on column test.c is 'Category name';
```

We have table with three columns, two of them are commented. Now run this code block (you can change it to procedure if you want):

```
declare 
  v_table varchar2(30) := 'TEST';
  v_sql varchar2(4000);
begin
  select listagg(column_name|| case when comments is not null then ' as "'||comments||'"' end,', ')
         within group (order by column_id)
    into v_sql
    from user_tab_columns 
    left join user_col_comments using (table_name, column_name)
    where table_name = v_table;
  v_sql := 'create or replace view vw_'||v_table||'_comments as select '||v_sql||' from '||v_table;
  execute immediate v_sql;
end;
```

This code created a view `vw_test_comments` dynamically. You can query it:

```
select * from vw_test_comments;
```

Result where headers are replaced with comments where they were defined (columns A and C):

```
    Id B  Category name
------ -- -------------
     1 B1 C101
     2 B2 C102
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=662fc5a0e43874f57c187f88598ee20d)</sup>**

If you want to do it with table from another schema then use `all_tab_columns`, `all_col_comments` and add `owner` in query.

Comment: Great! This is useful!

Answer (score 0):

**Simply you can change the header with comment as selecting table name as alias 
like as**:

```
   Select col1 as comment1 , col2 as comment2 from table
```

*Setting up alias during select statement is simple and proper way of doing*

Comment: There are too many fields, so I don't want to use "AS" to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use dynamic alias or so on

```
 select  c.Name as ColumnName,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
 from sys.tables t 
 inner join sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id 
 where t.name = 'tableName'
```

with this query you get columnsNames from your table
try to implement to your query and please let me know, if it helps a little

so you should use something like

```
 Select col1 as  (select  c.Name as ColumnName,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
 from sys.tables t 
 inner join sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id 
 where t.name = 'tableName' and rownum = @yourrownum) + @yourvariable from table
```